# Long Loading Times for HoloLens 2 Unity App

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, azure-cognitive-services, hololens, mrtk

I recently inherited a project for HoloLens 2 using Unity 2019.4.11f and an old version of MRTK. My job on the project has been integrating text-to-speech, which I have done using Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech. So far, things work great in the editor, but when the app is deployed to the HoloLens, there is a significant lag during scene transitions (on the order of 10-20 seconds, or sometimes longer). The app also blacks out frequently during this loading period. All builds I have tried so far have been debug builds in Visual Studio. This issue was not present in the last build before I worked on this project, but I do not understand why or if my changes caused this issue.

So far, I am considering alternatives to Microsoft Cognitive Services for text-to-speech, but I would like to explore other solutions before making that change.

Does anyone have guidance on achieving faster scene transitions in Unity? My understanding is that `SceneManager.LoadScene()` is operating without a delay, so I want to understand why this bug is occurring.

I also fear that upgrading the version of Unity will lead to dependencies like MRTK breaking, which I have experienced before. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem persist on release/master builds?

Comment: that seems to have mitigated the lag issue--will do further testing and report back

Comment: that seems to have cut down the lag--thanks for the suggestion--but it doesn't yet explain why the app blacks out. will have to do more research and testing to see what could be causing that.